# Water is to hydro as wind is to?

Tags: adjectives, prefixes

What is the generic name or collective adjective for things associated with wind and wind-generated electricity ?

solar, hydro, anemoi?

Comment: Richard, try, try. Good Luck. Let's know what you found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far as I know there is no term for wind power comparable to **hydro** for wind power in common use, all discussions I have encountered speak of **wind power**.

However [Aeolian](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aeolian) (or Eolian if you are American) is an adjective defined by the Oxford Online dictionary as

> Relating to or arising from the action of the wind.

The origin of the word being the name of the Greek god of wind, Aeolus.

The dictionary says that the term is geological and gives an example contrasting *fluvial* and *aeolian* sediments, these being those left by rivers and those left by wind action respectively, but the same dictionary also contains an entry for [Aeolian Harp](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aeolian_harp) which it defines as

> A stringed instrument that produces musical sounds when a current of air passes through it.

so there is at least one example of its use outside geology.

As I said above there does not seem to be a commonly accepted equivalent of **hydro** for wind power but **aeolian** (or eolian) seems like a good candidate to me if one is required.

Comment: Although, to confuse things, steam comes into play: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeolipile

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Yes, but the ancient Greeks did not, so fat as I know, understand the existence of air as a fluid gas and considered the wind to be some other sort of force. Hero probably thought of his steam engine as summoning the power of Aeolus to turn the ball rather than, as Newcomen, Treivithick, Watt and the other steam power pioneers did, understanding the differences in pressure.